# Why are my bones sometimes anchored and sometimes disconnected?

Tags: armature, bones

It seems to occur after symmetrizing. I'll test whether this is always the case. After the opposite is created, I click a bone and manipulate it, but the bone is not anchored to the armature. It is connected to the other bones in the limb--like, the arm, or leg. But the limbs are not anchored to the spine. This happens only to the symmetrized side.
But, this does not happen EVERY time. I think I am repeating the same steps, but I receive different results. I parent the mesh with the armature with automatic weight.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.